# Referencing a text field property using delegate methods

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I went through some source code that illustrated the basic use of text fields and the implementation of delegate methods belonging to the text field delegate protocol. Now while I understood the majority of the code, I am not certain about why or how one can reference the text field object in the delegate methods without referring to the name of the text field property.

So let's say you have a text field property called `myCrazyTextField` in your view controller, then why or how can you in a delegate method such as:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

refer to your text field object using only 'textField'?

As in, I am wondering why is it not:

```
myCrazyTextField.resignFirstResponder()
```

instead of

`textField.resignFirstResponder()` ?

Comment: are you set the delegate of `myCrazyTextField`

Comment: Assuming you have set textField.delegate = self. set the tag of textfield e.g "textField.tag = 1" and use it in delegate method to access particualar field.
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
if textField.tag == 1{   
 textField.resignFirstResponder() 
}
    return true
}

Comment: If you are using ` myCrazyTextField`  there is no diff . Because you have set  myCrazyTextField.delegate = self and now that delegate is refer  to  textFieldShouldReturn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We those delegate methods are generic. They will work only for those textfields for which you do the following

```
myCrazyTextField.delegate=self
```

Once you do that those textfields will respond to your method `textFieldShouldReturn`

Inside the method then you can individually identify your textfields like

```
if textfield == myCrazyTextField
```

Comment: Does that also mean that if I do not give the text field properties individual tags, but have set their delegates, that the delegate methods will work for the currently active textfield regardless (I will use the if statement, I am just wondering how it would go if you reference using textField in the case that you have more than one text field's delegate set.

Comment: yes it would work for the currently active textfield regardless of if. If is a more safe way to do it and a good way to ofcourse segregate the code if you want each textfield to do a different thing in the method. If you want the same code to be run for all textfields, remove the if and you should be fine.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot. What do you think about the method of using tags to reference them individually rather than by their property name as in your method here? Is it just that it might be less clear inside the code which one is tagged with what number, or does giving them tags offer any other advantages?

Comment: Its just unique way of identifying with tags. There are different opinions out there that referencing with tags and comparing with it might be faster as compared to properties directly but with swift and then again with the memory and RAM capabilities of devices these days, i think it would hardly matter. So I prefer to compare directly to get more readability in code. But yeah choice is yours.

Answer (score 1):

You can use both `myCrazyTextField` and `textField`. `textField` refer to the currently active text field.

Answer (score 1):

Set the delegate to self, and put a unique tag for the textField to know which textField did enter the method.

```
YourTextfield.delegate = self

YourTextfield.tag = 1
```

And inside the delegate method:

```
If (textfield.tag == 1){ //YourTextfield is the textfield referenced}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It does indeed help, thank you, but I am not sure how you declared the tag here? Also, as a side question, is this method of adding a unique tag preferable to just doing an if check using property name, as in, if textfield == myCrazyTextField vs. if textfield.tag == 1, etc.?

Comment: I edited my comment. Sorry I couldn't see the format while writing it since I was typing it on mobile. Please check and come back to me

Comment: Hi, no worries. Please see my last question - I am just wondering about pros and cons regarding referencing individual text fields via tags, vs. referencing them by name as kapsym does above? Do you have any opinions on this or is there any reason why you chose this method over the other one?

Comment: If you don't use tags, you will need to make the textfield global (define it up in the class). The tag allow you to reference it in the deelgate functionwithout defining it globally. So imagine a tableView with textfield in each cell, you cant define each one in the header. You use the tag instead to give each textfield the a unique id (indexPath.row in case of UITableView)

Comment: In this particular app they are defined in the class, but I will definitely look into this for table views now that you brought that up. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have several `UITextField`s in a single `ViewController`, each delegate method of `UITextField` gets called for each of your textfields as long as in `Storyboard` or in code you set the `ViewController` as the delegate of the specific textfield using

`yourTextfield.delegate = self`.

You can check which textfield is currently referred to by `textfield` in the delegate method, but if you want your delegate method to work on all of your textfields, you don't need to do this.